# Prove the normal approximation of beta distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How should I prove the normal approximation of beta distribution as follows:

Let $\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2}\sim \mathrm{Beta}(r_1, r_2)$, then prove that

$\sqrt{r_1+r_2} (\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2}- \dfrac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}) \to \mathrm N(0, \gamma(1-\gamma))$

where $r_1, r_2 \to \infty$ and $\frac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}\to \gamma$  $(0<\gamma<1)$.

My attempt: By some calculation, I figured out that $\mathbb E(\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2})=\dfrac{r_1}{r_1+r_2}$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2})=\dfrac{r_1 r_2}{(r_1 + r_2)^2 (r_1 +r_2 +1)}$.

Therefore, it remains to prove that $\sqrt{r_1 + r_2}\dfrac{\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2}-\mathbb E(\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2})}}$ converges to $Z \sim \mathrm N(0, 1)$.

Here I think I have to apply CLT, but I don't know how to because the given quantity does not contain sample mean. Does anyone have ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked whether the sum of two iid beta variables is again a beta variable (or presumably a multiple thereof)? That seems quite plausible to me, and it would do the job. (The buzzword here would be that the beta distribution is "infinitely divisible", if it turns out that it is.)

Comment: @Ian Unfortunately not. The sum of beta distributions is known as Irwin-Hall distribution.

Comment: I see. In that case I'd be inclined to check the characteristic function (so you're dealing with asympotics of $F(\gamma z,(1-\gamma)z,t)$ as $z \to \infty$ for $F$ the confluent hypergeometric function).

Comment: Did you try it with moment generating function? See whether it converges to the one of a normal distribution.

Comment: @Elsa The form of mgf is so complicated that I couldn't attempt to try.

Comment: @Ian I have never learned about hypergeometric function and characteristic function. I can only deal with this problem based on knowledges of undergraduate mathematical statistics.

Comment: @bellcircle It's a sum with a term $t^k/k!$ ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) . It looks as this sum converges to something of the form $e^{something(t)}$ which should then be the mgf of a normal. S

Comment: @Elsa And I am not sure whether I can interchange infinite sum and limit.

Comment: @bellcircle Take the sum up to some $N$ then show that the remaining summands' sum converges to zero if $N$ gets large. For this you might need $0<\gamma<1$. Further, note that the "1+..." of the mgf of the Beta can be written as $e^{0t}/0!$.

Comment: I find a great tutorial on this topic: https://study.com/academy/lesson/beta-distribution-definition-equations-examples.html

Answer (score 4):

Represent your $B_{r_1,r_2}$ as $\Gamma_{r_1}/(\Gamma_{r_1}+\Gamma_{r_2}).$ The $\Gamma_r$ distributions are asymptotically normal as $r\to\infty$ by the CLT.  Now get your result by applying the delta method.

Comment: What is the delta method?

Comment: The [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) is replacing a non-linear function with its 1 term Taylor expansion, to simplify distribution limit calculations.

Comment: +1, nice. I thought there had to be an infinitely divisible distribution lurking around somewhere...

Comment: @kimchilover I see, and I tried it before but it didn't work since $\theta$ is fixed in delta method but $r_1$ and $r_2$  go to infinity.

Comment: Try harder.  $\gamma$ is your friend here: it is fixed.

Comment: @kimchilover Thanks a lot. I'm almost done.

Answer (score 2):

Want
$\sqrt{a+b}(B(a,b)-\frac{a}{a+b})
\to N(0, c(1-c))
$
where
$\frac{a}{a+b}
\to c$.

If
$\frac{a}{a+b}
\to c$,
then
$a \approx cr$
and
$b \approx (1-c)r$
as
$r \to \infty$.

However,
I get,
for large $r$
and
$0 < c < 1$,
that
$B(cr, (1-c)r)
\approx \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{(c^c(1-c)^{1-c})^r}{\sqrt{c(1-c)r}}
$
so
$\sqrt{r}B(cr, (1-c)r)
\approx \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{(c^c(1-c)^{1-c})^r}{\sqrt{c(1-c)}}
$
which does not 
seem to agree.

Here is my derivation.

$\begin{array}\\
B(a, b)
&=\int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\\
&\approx\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi /a}(a/e)^a\sqrt{2\pi /b}(b/e)^b}{\sqrt{2\pi/ (a+b)}((a+b)/e)^{a+b}}
\qquad\text{for large } a, b\\
&=\sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{a^{a-1/2}b^{b-1/2}}{(a+b)^{a+b-1/2}}\\
\end{array}
$

For
$a=cr, b=(1-c)r$
we have
$r = a+b$
and
$\dfrac{a}{a+b}
=c
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
B(a, b)
&=B(cr, (1-c)r)\\
&\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{(cr)^{cr-1/2}((1-c)r)^{(1-c)r-1/2}}{r^{r-1/2}}\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{c^{cr-1/2}(1-c)^{(1-c)r-1/2}r^{cr-1/2}r^{(1-c)r-1/2}}{r^{r-1/2}}\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{c^{cr-1/2}(1-c)^{(1-c)r-1/2}r^{r-1}}{r^{r-1/2}}\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{c^{cr}(1-c)^{(1-c)r}}{\sqrt{c(1-c)r}}\\
&= \sqrt{2\pi}\dfrac{(c^c(1-c)^{1-c})^r}{\sqrt{c(1-c)r}}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward approach is to compute the Taylor series expansion of $f(\mu + \sigma t)$ where $f$ is the pdf of Beta$(r_1, r_2)$ and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are its mean and variance. An advantage of this approach is that you get convergence rates, but it may be overkill for what you've asked.

I have done this computation in Lemma A.1 of the paper https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejs/1472829397

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the answer:

Let $\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2} = \dfrac{V_1}{V_1+V_2}$ where $V_1 \sim \chi^2(2r_1 ) = \mathrm{Gamma}(r_1, 2)$ and $V_2 \sim \chi^2(2r_2 ) = \mathrm{Gamma}(r_2, 2)$ and $V_1, V_2$ are independent.

Now we know that $\dfrac{V_1-2r_1}{\sqrt{4r_1}} \to \mathrm N(0, 1)$ as $r_1\to\infty$ and $\dfrac{V_2-2r_2}{\sqrt{4r_2}} \to \mathrm N(0, 1)$ as $r_2\to\infty$. Therefore, $\sqrt{r_1+r_2}(\dfrac{V_1-2r_1}{\sqrt{4r_1(r_1+r_2)}}, \dfrac{V_2-2r_2}{\sqrt{4r_2(r_1+r_2)}})^t \to \mathrm N_2(0, I)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Also, $\sqrt{r_1+r_2}\left(\dfrac{V_1-2r_1}{\sqrt{4r_1(r_1+r_2)}}, \dfrac{V_2-2r_2}{\sqrt{4r_2(r_1+r_2)}}\right)^t\sim \sqrt{n}\left(\dfrac {V_1}{\sqrt{4\gamma}n}-\sqrt{\gamma}, \dfrac {V_2}{\sqrt{4(1-\gamma)}n}-\sqrt{1-\gamma} \right)^t$

Where $r_1+r_2=n, r_1 \sim \gamma n, r_2 \sim (1-\gamma)n$.

Now let $g(x, y)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\gamma}x}{\sqrt{\gamma}x+\sqrt{1-\gamma}y}$, then $g'(x, y)=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{\gamma (1-\gamma)}y}{\left(\sqrt{\gamma}x+\sqrt{1-\gamma}y\right)^2}, -\dfrac{\sqrt{\gamma (1-\gamma)}x}{\left(\sqrt{\gamma}x+\sqrt{1-\gamma}y\right)^2} \right)^t$.

Therefore, $\sqrt{n}\left( g\left(\dfrac {V_1}{\sqrt{4\gamma}n}, \dfrac {V_2}{\sqrt{4(1-\gamma)}n} \right)-g\left(\sqrt{\gamma}, \sqrt{1-\gamma}\right)  \right)=\sqrt{n}(\mathrm B_{r_1, r_2}-\gamma)\to g'\left(\sqrt{\gamma}, \sqrt{1-\gamma}\right)^t\mathrm N(0, I) = \mathrm N(0, \gamma(1-\gamma))$

Am I right?

Comment: @kimchilover Please check if my solution is correct and whether there are some logical defects.

Comment: I think so.  If I were writing it I'd stick in words like *delta method* or *Taylor expansion* between the last 2 sentences, and a formula like $B=g(V_1/\ldots, V_2/\ldots) $ and so on, to make the flow of formulas less formidable.